# How to show that energy is monotonically increasing?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Particle of mass $m$ is moving on a straight line under the influence of a force generated by a potential and friction with the equation of motion: $$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2 \gamma \frac{dx}{dt} = -V'(x) $$

They say  $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}E = \frac{d}{dt} \bigg[\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+V(x)\bigg] \color{blue}= -2\gamma \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 \le 0$ so $E$ is monotically increasing.

Could someone please explain the second/blue equality? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the movement equation by $\dot x$ we have

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12 m\dot x^2 + V(x)\right) = -\gamma \dot x ^2
$$

but

$$
E = \frac 12 m\dot x^2 + V(x)  \;\;\mbox{the so called mechanical energy}
$$

hence

$$
\frac{d}{dt}E = -\gamma \dot x ^2 \le 0
$$

the mechanical energy decays according to the work realized by the dissipative forces.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Cesareo's answer, you can also differentiate directly using the chain rule on both terms:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{m}{2} \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + V(x) \right)
= \frac{m}{2} \cdot 2\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \frac{dV}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\left(m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + V'(x)\right), $$
and then use your equation of motion to obtain the blue equality.